# Is there a way to allow a drop down menu inside of a drop down menu, or some other double selection in a single cell?

Tags: excel, combobox, userform

I am creating a form for work, and the customer wants to be able to select both 'call date' and 'call time' in a single cell. The options for 'call date' and 'call time' are pulled from two different tables. I have created a userform with two comboboxes in it. However, when I try to populate them with a table, I get an error message indicating that ComboBox1 is not recognized as an object. Any idea why this is happening? This is the code that I'm using:

````
Date_Time_Userform.Show

'Populate Combo list values

ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 1

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

Set myTable = Worksheets("Reference Tables").ListObjects("Call Date:")

myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange

ComboBox1.List = myArray

End Sub```
````

Comment: A cell can only have one value. Maybe you need a userform.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the tip. Would you have any ideas about the combobox not being recognized as an object?

Comment: `Dim myForm As Date_Time_Userform`, `Set myForm = New Date_Time_Userform`, then `myForm.ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 1` - my guess.